# Overlay home screen like Facebook chatheads

Tags: ios

I was wondering how I would create a small pop-up "subview" that appears on top of all apps and the home screen much like the Facebook chatheads?

I've seen plenty of threads on how to do this in android, but I was wondering how you would implement this in IOS obj-c?

Comment: Do you mean like a notification?

Comment: No, I mean a movable small application that sits on the top of all views, like a widget.

Comment: On top of other apps is not possible, on top of your own app you just have to add a view to your window.

Comment: Already knew how to do this but ah well, I was just wondering if it was possible!

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that on iOS unless you are developing for JailBroken device.